# Problem converting a latex document from amsart to report document class

Tags: errors, document-classes, amsart, report

I am currently writing a latex document using the document class `amsart`, but I was told it was better to use another document class for my thesis. I therefore tried the `report` document class, but I got many error-messages. I tried to delete much of the text I had written above the start of the document (`\newtheorem` `\newcommand` and so forth), but it still doesn't run. Does anyone have any tips for how to change from `amsart` document class to `report` class (or some other document class which a thesis could be written in)? I am using `pdflatex`.

This is what I have written before the introduction:

```
    \documentclass[reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\graphicspath{ latex }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{esdiff}

\newcommand{\vhtable}{\rule{30pt}{30pt}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\bU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\bH}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}
\newcommand{\pw}{p^w}
\newcommand{\epsw}{\varepsilon^w}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ud}{u^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\md}{m^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\nd}{n^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\psid}{\psi_{\delta}}
\newcommand{\cde}{c^{\delta}}
\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\mde}{m^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\nde}{n^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\ude}{u^{\delta}}

\newcommand\MyTabHeadings{% 
\rowcolor{Tab}\rowstyle{\bfseries\color{white}}}
\newcommand{\mT}{\widetilde{m}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newtheorem{deff}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline#1{%
    \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}%
    \nl@org@contentsline{#1}%
  }%
}


\protected\def\numberline#1{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\nl@align{%
      nl@align@%
      \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
    }%
    \edef\nl@align{%
      \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
      \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
      \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
    }{%
      \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

% Implementations of `\numberline` for the different horizontal alignments
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{% left-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% centered
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% right-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
}


\def\nl@align@{l}% default
\def\nl@align@section{r}

\makeatletter    
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{1}{0,2pt}{6pc}{8mm}{\ \ }} 
\makeatother

\makeatletter    
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{0.2pt}{2pc}{8mm}{\ \ }} 

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\makenomenclature
\makeglossary
\makeatletter
%Table of Contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Add bold to \section titles in ToC and remove . after numbers
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\bfseries\ignorespaces#1 #2\quad}}\bfseries#3}
% Remove . after numbers in \subsection
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2\quad}}#3}
%\let\tocsubsubsection\tocsubsection% Update for \subsubsection
%...

\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus1em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima{#6}\nobreak
    \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
    \nobreak
    \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{\ifnum#1=1\bfseries\fi#7}}\par% <-- \bfseries for \section page
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname r@tocindent0\endcsname{0pt}
}
\makeatother
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
\normalsize


\newpage
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \tableofcontents
}

\makeatletter
\let\toc@pre\relax
\let\toc@post\relax
\makeatother
```

This is the first error message I get:

```
  { ! LaTeX Error: \tocsection undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.150     \renewcommand{\tocsection}
                                    [3]{%
? }
```

Comment: As a first start, after your `\documentclass` line, add `\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}` and see if that works. (And don't change anything else).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried adding that, but I got the same error-message.

Comment: Take a look at the `amsart` documentation and look for commands that it defines, then comment out those lines in your file.  There's a list in Table 1 of the docs.  The class also defines `\specialsection` so if you've used that, it will also give an error.

Comment: if you want help with an error message it is best if you show the error message, show the full message from the log file from `!` to `?`  use `{}` in this site's editor to mark it as a code block so line endings are preserved.

Comment: I have updated the question in order to try to include what you mentioned.

Comment: `\tocsection` is defined in amsart but not in report class so that needs to be `\newcommand` not `\renewcommand` or simply delete it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply! I tried to do that, but then I got {! LaTeX Error: Command \@dotsep already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.182 \newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
                              
? }

Comment: Should I change all {\renewcommand} to {\newcommand} ?

Comment: No just the ones it tells you about (just three I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preamble is rather strange but this runs without error (with a warning about duplicated destinations but that will probably resolve itself once you have more text)  I added comments where I changed your input

```
   \documentclass[reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% don't need this twice \usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
% don't need this \usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
% don't need this \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% don't need this\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tensor}
% don't need this twice \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
% don't need this three times \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% don't need this aready loaded by ccolor\usepackage{colortbl}
% don't need this twice \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{nomencl}

% no \graphicspath{ latex } or \graphicspath{ {latex} } 
% don't need this, certainly no point in it being here
% \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% No!\ProvidesPackage{esdiff}

\newcommand{\vhtable}{\rule{30pt}{30pt}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\bU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\bH}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}
\newcommand{\pw}{p^w}
\newcommand{\epsw}{\varepsilon^w}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ud}{u^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\md}{m^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\nd}{n^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\psid}{\psi_{\delta}}
\newcommand{\cde}{c^{\delta}}
\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\mde}{m^{\delta}}% same as \md ?
\newcommand{\nde}{n^{\delta}}% same as \nd ?
\newcommand{\ude}{u^{\delta}}% same as \ud ?

\newcommand\MyTabHeadings{% 
\rowcolor{Tab}\rowstyle{\bfseries\color{white}}}
\newcommand{\mT}{\widetilde{m}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newtheorem{deff}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline#1{%
    \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}%
    \nl@org@contentsline{#1}%
  }%
}


\protected\def\numberline#1{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\nl@align{%
      nl@align@%
      \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
    }%
    \edef\nl@align{%
      \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
      \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
      \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
    }{%
      \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

% Implementations of `\numberline` for the different horizontal alignments
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{% left-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% centered
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% right-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
}


\def\nl@align@{l}% default
\def\nl@align@section{r}

\makeatletter    
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{1}{0,2pt}{6pc}{8mm}{\ \ }} 
\makeatother

\makeatletter    
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{0.2pt}{2pc}{8mm}{\ \ }} 

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\makenomenclature
\makeglossary
\makeatletter
%Table of Contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Add bold to \section titles in ToC and remove . after numbers

% just don't define this or use new not renew
%\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
%  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\bfseries\ignorespaces#1 #2\quad}}\bfseries#3}
% Remove . after numbers in \subsection
%\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{%
%  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2\quad}}#3}
%\let\tocsubsubsection\tocsubsection% Update for \subsubsection
%...

%\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}

\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus1em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima{#6}\nobreak
    \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
    \nobreak
    \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{\ifnum#1=1\bfseries\fi#7}}\par% <-- \bfseries for \section page
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi}

%%% new not renew
\AtBeginDocument{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname r@tocindent0\endcsname{0pt}
}
\makeatother
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle
zzz
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
\normalsize

zzz
%%missing
\end{abstract}

\newpage
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \tableofcontents
\clearpage
}

\makeatletter
\let\toc@pre\relax
\let\toc@post\relax
\makeatother

zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It worked fine in my whole document when I deleted the lines including {tocline}.